# Below what network speed should I be using compression for an rsync transfer?

Tags: networking, rsync, file-transfer, compression

I'm transferring some files from a remote server. The speeds for the transfer are abysmal (~1 MBps), and have got me thinking about optimizing the transfer for speed.

At what network speed does it become the best option to use compression? This seems like a fairly simple question but about 20 minutes of searching google and the stackexchange websites hasn't got me the answer I'm looking for. I know that it is useful to use the -z flag at 'low' network speeds, but I haven't seen anyone frame the answer to this question in practical terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would depend on the size of the file ... If it was going to take more than 5 minutes at the normal rate to transfer, it would be a good idea to use compression.

Here's a good article that explains how to effectively use compression:
http://www.tonido.com/blog/index.php/2009/04/09/network-file-transfer-with-on-the-fly-compression/#.U17LovldUpo

Comment: thanks. the files in question are about 300 MB to 2GB in size